Derivation of update rule for Off-policy TD(0) with importance sampling ratio
Sutton-Barto, second edt, page 128, Exercise 6.7:

Design an off-policy version of the TD(0) update that can be used with
arbitrary target policy $\pi$ and covering behavior policy $b$, using at each step t the importance sampling ratio $\rho_{t:t}$ (5.3).

The answer is:
$V(S_t) \leftarrow  V(S_t) + \alpha\rho_{t:t}\left[R_{t+1} + V(S_{t+1})-V(S_t)\right]$
Normally, if we make a similarity to Monte Carlo method, the target here is $R_{t+1} + V(S_{t+1})$ and hence I was expecting the answer as:
$V(S_t) \leftarrow  V(S_t) + \alpha\left[\rho_{t:t}(R_{t+1} + V(S_{t+1}))-V(S_t)\right]$
Where is my mistake? Or, is the answer wrong?

Where are you getting the official answer from? They are not published in the book.

I have the solutions manual.

There is more than one place with published solutions. You can even get them from Sutton if you contact him and ask. Please give more information, link if online.

Please, put your specific question in the title. "off-policy TD(0)" is far from being a good title because it could be about 100 things.
